# count equal fields of 2 Tables and Inner join with 3rd

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have 3 tables

```
Table cases: docket is pk 
| docket |   dt_file  |
-----------------------
|AA-0322 | 01-22-2015 |
|AA-0431 | 03-21-2014 |


Table parties:
|  id  |  docket  |  name  |
----------------------------
|   1  |  AA-0322 |  Bob   |
|   2  |  AA-0322 |  John  |


Table motions:
|  id  |  docket  |  motion |
-----------------------------
|  1   | AA-0322  |  Summons|
|  2   | AA-0322  |  Guilty |
```

I want to count the number of fields in parties and motion that have the same docket and then make a table  with table.cases with the dt_file

example:

```
| docket | party_count | motion_count| dt_file |
 -----------------------------------------------
  AA-0322|       2     |        2    | 02-22-2015|
```

I also want to filter by dt_file, so adding a WHERE statement ex:

```
WHERE YEAR(dt_file) = '2015'
```

So far i've came up with this, but I havn't had success joining table.cases with dt_file correctly.

```
SELECT p.docket, p.party_count, m.motion_count
FROM
    (SELECT docket, COUNT(docket) AS party_count
     FROM parties
     GROUP BY docket) AS p
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT docket, COUNT(docket) AS motion_count
     FROM motions
     GROUP BY docket) AS m
ON p.docket = m.docket
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems correct.  You just need to add `cases` to the `from` clause:

```
SELECT c.docket, p.party_count, m.motion_count, c.dt_file
FROM cases c JOIN
     (SELECT docket, COUNT(docket) AS party_count
      FROM parties
      GROUP BY docket
     ) p
     ON c.docket = p.docket INNER JOIN
     (SELECT docket, COUNT(docket) AS motion_count
      FROM motions
      GROUP BY docket
     ) m
     ON c.docket = m.docket;
```

If you want all dockets, even those where there are no motions or parties, then use `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

Let this be another example.

```
Select
    p.docket,
    COUNT(p.docket) As party_count,
    COUNT(m.docket) As motion_count,
    p.dt_file
From
    cases As c
        Inner Join  parties As p
            On  c.docket = p.docket
        Inner Join  motions As m
            On  c.docket = m.docket
Group By
    p.docket,
    p.dt_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.docket, p.party_count, m.motion_count, c.dt_file
FROM
    (SELECT docket, COUNT(docket) AS party_count
     FROM parties
     GROUP BY docket) AS p
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT docket, COUNT(docket) AS motion_count
     FROM motions
     GROUP BY docket) AS m
    ON p.docket = m.docket
INNER JOIN cases c
    ON p.docket = c.docket
WHERE YEAR(c.dt_file) = '2015'
```